# How to override protected method in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to override protected method by rewrite class in magento2.
I want to overrride and change code when you save attribute multi select option from backend here is my code.

```
<?php 
 namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Model\ResourceModel\Entity;
 class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute 
 {
    protected function _updateAttributeOption($object, $optionId, $option)
    {
        //custom code 
    }
 }
```

Second method I want to rewrite for set attribute option value when you edit multi select attribute.

```
<?php
 namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options;
 class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Options
 {
      protected $_template = 'Testmodule_TestAttribute::catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml';

      protected function _prepareUserDefinedAttributeOptionValues($option, $inputType, $defaultValues)
      {
            //custom code 
      }
 }
```

This is my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Options" type="Drc\Attributeimage\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Options" />
    <preference for="Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute" type="Testmodule\Testattribute\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute" /> 
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Form" type="Testmodule\Testattribute\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Form" /> 
</config>
```

This is form file I want to change form enctype property

```
 <?php
  namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit;

  class Form extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Form
  {
     protected function _prepareForm()
     {
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'),'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'post']]
    );
       $form->setUseContainer(true);
       $this->setForm($form);
       return parent::_prepareForm();
     }
  }
```

Please Help me for override this **protected methods** in magento2.

Comment: what is the issue are available after use above methods any errors?

Answer (score 1):

For first method override use below code,

```
<?php 
 namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Model\ResourceModel\Entity;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute as EntityAttribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

 class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute 
 {
    protected function _updateAttributeOption($object, $optionId, $option)
    {
        //custom code 
    }
 }
```

For second method,

```
<?php
 namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options;

 use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection;

 class Options extends Magento\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Options
 {
      protected $_template = 'Testmodule_TestAttribute::catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml';

      protected function _prepareUserDefinedAttributeOptionValues($option, $inputType, $defaultValues)
      {
            //custom code 
      }
 }
```

For **form prepareform override** use below methods,

```
<?php
namespace Testmodule\Testattribute\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form as DataForm;

  class Form extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Form
  {
     protected function _prepareForm()
     {
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'),'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'post']]
    );
       $form->setUseContainer(true);
       $this->setForm($form);
       return parent::_prepareForm();
     }
  }
```

Remove var folder and try again.

Comment: other method is working but  this method _updateAttributeOption() is not calling from my file.